# ModelMultipleChoiceField passing request.user

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to use `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` in a form. I know it takes a queryset, however the query set I will be using take the param user which I normally pass in a view using request.user. However this is in a form, how do I pass request.user? do I need to?

```
Entry.objects.filter(request.user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override your form's init method:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            form_choices = Entry.objects.filter(user)
        else:
            form_choices = Entry.objects.all()

        self.fields['my_mfield'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                       queryset=form_choices
                                   )
```

and in your views, when it's time to instantiate the form:

```
form = MyForm(request.user)
```

or

```
form = MyForm()
```

Comment: Just a work of note: You're setting the wrong variable name in the constructor choices in above example should be a queryset.

Comment: sorry, I think I'm missing it... form_choices is a queryset O_o

Comment: choices=form_choices will need to be defined as queryset=form_choices or it will throw and error from my understanding.

Comment: Damn. Totally missed that, updating asap! Good spotting!

Comment: No worries, I was looking for something similar and your answer help me out, just wanted to point that out tho. :)